# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: createdDate_MOD of: org.baeldung.HibernateAuditDemo.model.Order_AUD

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I use hibernate envers for auditing.

I have simple `Order` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Audited
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;

    private Double price;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar createdDate;

    public Order() {
    }
    //the rest is unimportant
```

I use `AuditorReader` to query for revisions at which property has changed:

```
    AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
            // find revision at which order entity changed its property createdDate
            List revisions = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Order.class, false, true).
            add(AuditEntity.property("createdDate").hasChanged()).getResultList();

            Object[] history = (Object[]) revisions.get(0);
```

In this code I get exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: createdDate_MOD of: org.baeldung.HibernateAuditDemo.model.Order_AUD [select e__, r from org.baeldung.HibernateAuditDemo.model.Order_AUD e__, org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity r where e__.createdDate_MOD = :_p0 and e__.originalId.REV.id = r.id order by e__.originalId.REV.id asc]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1967)
```

In database in table `orders` and `orders_aud`, I see column named `createdDate` but not `createdDate_MOD`.

Why can't property `createdDate` be resolved?

Answer (score 3):

To tell hibernate envers track changes to certain property you need to set `@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)` on that property.

To set it globally for all entities you need to set `org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag` to true in hibernate properties.

Answer (score 1):

The Volodymir's answer perfectly explains what one needs to do in order to invoke `AuditEntity.property("some_property").hasChanged()` method.

**However, some may experience the same mysterious exception when not using the `hasChanged` method - just like me.**

For this setup:

```
@Entity(name = "prnt")
@Audited
public class ParentClass {
    @Id private Long id;
}

@Entity(name = "chld")
@Audited
public class ChildClass {
    @Id private Long id;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "shrt_prnt_id") 
    private ParentClass looongishLinkToParentClass;
}
```

...one may expect this to work:

```
AuditQuery q = ...;
q.add(AuditEntity.property("shrt_prnt_id")).eq(value));
```

..or, at least, this:

```
q.add(AuditEntity.property("looongishLinkToParentClass")).eq(value));
```

Neither of these do work!

**This one does:**

```
q.add(AuditEntity.property("looongishLinkToParentClass_id")).eq(value));
```

Comment: q.add(AuditEntity.property("looongishLinkToParentClass_id")).eq(value));
save my day , thank you